java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no otmcjni in java.library.path while connecting DigitalPersona fingerprint device
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no otmcjni in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.MatchingLibrary.<clinit>(MatchingLibrary.java:16)
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.Matcher.<clinit>(Matcher.java:8)
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.processing._impl.DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl$EnrollmentImpl.<init>(DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.processing._impl.DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl.createEnrollment(DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl.java:20)

where can I download otmcjni ? Any suggestions??
I was checking digitalpersona website to download any integration document. But didn't find any.

Looks like you don't have the binary library (a DLL or Unix shared library) installed
